# How to create Timer Task OUTSIDE onCreate in Android Studio?

Tags: android, timer

So I have a very stupid problem. I am able to create a simple timer task that ticks every second:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (counter == 0) {
                            //Reload Map...
                            timer.cancel();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            TimeLabel.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                            counter = counter - 1;
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

After one minute, it will reload my google map. But when I try to open other activity, and try to go back to Map, my MapsActivity is not killed, (even though I used `finish();`). That's is why my timer is overlapping.

I have a guess that I should create the timer OUTSIDE onCreate, but didn't success in doing so. Can you help me guys?

Comment: You should make your timer a global variable inside your class and you can cancel/stop it `onPause` or `onDestroy` methods

Comment: Sir how can I do it? Do you have any sample on how to create it outside? Thank you in advanced sir!

Comment: Yes sir... Teach me more Master ^_^

Comment: Any luck @Christina?

Comment: compiling sir @NaviRamyle! ^_^

Comment: Saved my life sir! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, you can add on skype if want, check my profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Global Variables
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask task;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Make a method to make it cleaner
        setTimer();
    }

    private void setTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (counter == 0) {
                            //Reload Map...
                            timer.cancel();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            TimeLabel.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                            counter = counter - 1;
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //This will be called after onCreate or your activity is resumed
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //This will be called if the app is sent to background or the phone is locked
        //Also this prevent you from duplicating the instance of your timer
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```